# Linux Mint для хакера

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Можно ли использовать Linux Mint для пентеста?

P.S: Linux Mint - мой первый Linux

Comment: Разрешаю. Подпись. Печать.

Comment: Кто-то посмотрел `who am i?` и решил, что бегать от ментов попутно руля светофорами - круто? Ну тогда начни хотя бы с долгого (очень, ОЧЕНЬ долго, несколько лет, на самом деле) чтения документации про все слова, которые услышишь начиная от "операционные системы" и "компьютерные сети", заканчивая "Язык программирования Си".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ответ субъективный, скорее всего вопрос будет закрыт по этой же причине, т.к. нельзя дать объективный ответ.

Если вопрос в том, нужно ли устанавливать именно Kali Linux, то ответ нет. Можно использовать Debian, CentOS, Gentoo и др. Разницы особо не будет, особенно в самом начале пути.

Сама ОС не так важна, важен софт. Нужно уметь находить готовые продукты и, что более важно, писать собственные скрипты, эксплойты и т.п.

Comment: Важен даже не софт. Важен мозг и руки нужной кривизны. Опытный пентестер может поломать все, просто уснув на клавиатуре (и были прецеденты, когда дети, пытаясь разблокировать родительский комп, нашли символ, который крашил лок скрин и получали доступ. Два бага за раз от маленьких детей)